# How can I make vertical rectangle with border on left of the screen and a horizontal rectangle on top of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

I need to do a vertical and horizontal rectangles with coloured border. When they cross on the top left part, there should be a square with a logo inside. I need it to be responsive to the page crop so that the square and rectangles keep their scale.

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSK4w.jpg)

<-- language: html -->

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="logo_file" src="exemple_images/logo.jpg">
        </div>
            </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
            <div class="xxss_icons">
                <img class="icon" src="exemple_images/instagram.png">
                <img class="icon" src="exemple_images/facebook.png">
                <img class="icon" src="exemple_images/twitter.png">
            </div>
          </div>  
    </div>
    <div>
</div>
</body>
```

```css
  /* Header */
  .header {
      border: 1px solid #FCFF76;
      display: flex;
      font-size: 70px;
      text-align: center;
  }

 .logo {
      border-right: 1px solid #FCFF76;
      width: 9.5%;
      float: left;
  }
 .row {
    display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
  }
 /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a quick example. If you can, I would recommend you to use Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/), it is really easy to install and will help you to style things faster (and always responsive) ;)

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-right: solid yellow 1px;
  }

.square {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid yellow 1px;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
}

.navbar{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #111;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    border-bottom: solid yellow 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidenav.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar">
    </div>

    <div class="sidenav">
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```